# Include contents of POST request in log file

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I have a HTTP server that takes a JSON request of the form `{"a": 3, "b": 4}` and produces `{"answer": 7}` as a JSON response:

```
:- use_module(library(http/thread_httpd)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_dispatch)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_json)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_log)).

:- http_handler('/', handle_request, []).

% Start server on specified port.
server(Port) :-
    http_server(http_dispatch, [port(Port)]).

% Calculate a + b.
solve(_{a:A, b:B}, _{answer:N}) :-
    number_codes(X, A),  % Convert from string to number.
    number_codes(Y, B),
    N is X + Y.

handle_request(Request) :-
    http_log('~w~n', Request),  % <--- ATTENTION.
    http_read_json_dict(Request, Query),
    solve(Query, Solution),
    reply_json_dict(Solution).

:- server(9000).
```

I have added the `http_log('~w~n', Request)` line to log all requests to a file. However, the resulting log entries do not include the contents of the post request (i.e. `{"a":  3, "b": 4}`), which I would like to have for debugging purposes. This is what the log file looks like:

```
server(started, 1540001234).
/*Wed Oct 24 01:23:45 2018*/ request(1, 1540123456.789, [peer(ip(127,0,0,1)),method(post),request_uri(/),path(/),http_version(1-1),host(localhost),port(9000),user_agent('wizard/1.2.3'),connection('keep-alive'),content_type('application/json'),content_length(20)]).
protocol(http)
completed(1, 0.00123456, 12, 200, ok).
```

The question is: how can the contents of the POST request be included in the log file?

Comment: Look at [3.1.2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=request), which says you need to use `http_read_data/3` to acquire the rest of the request when it is a POST; it's literally sitting in the input stream waiting to be read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add for example the following directive:

```
:- initialization(set_setting(http:log_post_data, 2_000)).
```

To find out more, see the documentation of [add_post_data/2](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=http_log%3Aadd_post_data/2):

> Add a request field post_data(Data)
>  if the setting http:log_post_data is an integer > 0, the content length < this setting and nolog_post_content_type/1 does not succeed on the provided content type.

Comment: This adds a post data field to the logs (e.g. `post_data("eJyqVkpUslIw1FFQSgLSRrVcAAAAAP//AwAjEgOx")`), but the data is not human-readable. What is it encoded in?

Comment: It is ZIP-compressed and Base64 encoded. Please open a new question if you want to discuss how to decode it.